# Getting Hindu rope plants to branch

Tags: succulents, branches

I've had this Hindu rope plant for about two years and it has never branched at all. It was grown from a cutting, so I'm not sure if i should ever expect it to branch; I'm not very familiar with the nuances of these plants.

Is it possible to prompt it to branch, or is the only way to make it more balanced and less lanky to cut the end, re-root it, and plant it with the existing end?

My apologies for the rotated picture - that's not fixable to my knowledge within Stack Exchange, and rotating them on my desktop prior to uploading didn't help.

[image: Hindu rope plant]

Answer (score 2):

These plants don't really branch out, though you may get another stem starting to grow from the base at some point. This is a flowering plant commonly known as Hindu Rope plant, but its true name is Hoya carnosa 'compacta' - it takes a long time to flower, and the flowers tend to arise from the older growth. People often grow them in hanging baskets and allow them to trail downwards, or tie them to a support to keep them upright, removing only growth that is either damaged or is simply invading the space around it too far. Further information here https://www.houseplant411.com/houseplant/hindu-rope-plant-hoya-how-to-grow-care

Comment: Thank you! That's what I meant; not "branching" per se but growth of new stems from the base. How can I prompt it to grow a new stem? I've visited the link you shared before, but it doesn't have any information on that topic.

Comment: Try fertilizing it as recommended in the link.